# scrollbar resets when DOM is manipulated

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, scrollbar

So I've got a js function that's triggered when an option is chosen from a `<select>` element. This function triggers some DOM manipulation< and for whatever reason it makes the scrollbar shoot up to the top every time. This is frustrating, because I switched my old form data to ajax to avoid this problem.

I've researched this problem and found this:

[How to prevent page's scroll position reset after DOM manipulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704425/how-to-prevent-pages-scroll-position-reset-after-dom-manipulation)

But I'm not calling the function from a link, rather an onchange event within a select form, so I don't know how to apply the provided solutions.

Here's the form element calling the function:

```
<div id="imageTable">
   <form action="">
     <select onchange="getOption()" name="dir">
         <option value="Anotherguyly">Anotherguyly</option>
         <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
         <option value="page1">page1</option>
         <option value="pageish2">pageish2</option>
     </select>
   </form>
</div>
```

Here are the js functions in the header:

```
        function getOption() {
            var selectDOM = document.getElementById("imageTable").getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            var i = selectDOM.selectedIndex;
            var selectedChoices = selectDOM.options;
            var selectedText = selectedChoices[i].value
            resetImageTable(selectedText);
        }

        function resetImageTable(option) {
              // clears out previous DOM elements, inserts new chosen by the provided option
        }
```

Comment: is there any css attached to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the answer is in the order of execution. `clears out previous DOM elements` is *very* likely to influence the effective scroll position.

Rather than removing and then adding nodes, consider applying a CSS `visibility:hidden` to all current images, and then swapping them out for the newly loaded images. If there are fewer new than old, remove the stragglers at the end of the function call; if there are more new than old, then continue to add them beyond replacement.

This approach would result in minimal scroll position change.

Comment: Yes, that's the culprit... I don't know why I didn't think of it before, the whole table is taken away and rebuilt, so the scroll bar moves all the way up to accommodate for the massive loss of space. I think I'm gonna do something along the lines of what you described. Thanks Shad!